# GTFS and multiple routes

Tags: java, transport, gtfs

I am working with GTFS format.I have a concern for example consider a little complex network where a user want to travel from a source 'A' to Destination 'B' and actually there exist no direct route from A to B.But we can reach B from A thru a stop C. i cant see a way mentioned in GTFS to know that  there exist some route to reach B in our example(A->c->B). Do i miss something here? or there is no way to do that but to implement our own algo? or is some third party already implemented the algo in java (i believe someone did it ;) ).

Thanks in advance.

Cheers
Sriram.

PS:As i am unable to create new tags hence i have the transport,java tag (not gtfs or something similar to that)

Comment: That's a question that would fit perfectly with http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49339/open-transportation-technology

Comment: @gcamp the link is not available.

Comment: The proposal for a Transit information stack exchange site was denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well GTFS does not help in identifying paths across different routes and this has to be done on fly.

Answer (score 1):

As Sriram's answer from 4.5 years ago notes, GTFS does not attempt to represent all possible paths through a transit network. OpenTripPlanner is an open-source project that tries to solve this problem in the general case: http://www.opentripplanner.org/. OTP uses GTFS as its primary schedule input.